# How to sum in josql

Tags: java, josql

I am using JOSql for manipulation data in java
I want to get the sum of values in following query

```
 q.parse ("SELECT value,planType from com.mbcl.ytd.Enrolment group by planType");
```

i am trying to get the sum of value on bases of planType 
When i go with JOSql function as

```
 GroupingFunctions groupingFunctions = new GroupingFunctions();
 groupingFunctions.sum(aggregateList,"value")
```

it is giving me sum of all values how can I get sum form list using plan type.
plz guide me where I am missing

Comment: See the documentation at http://josql.sourceforge.net/manual/javadocs/org/josql/functions/GroupingFunctions.html

Comment: i have try that but i am not able to use expression.

Comment: try this       `SELECT country, 
@total 
FROM Details 
GROUP BY country 
LIMIT 1,1 
EXECUTE ON GROUP_BY_RESULTS sum(amount) AS total`  or `SELECT * 
FROM Details 
GROUP BY country 
GROUP BY ORDER :_allobjs.size DESC 
EXECUTE ON GROUP_BY_RESULTS sum(amount) AS total `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `q.parse ("SELECT sum(value),planType from com.mbcl.ytd.Enrolment group by planType");`